# Is there a quicker way to toggle Windows sticky keys?

Tags: accessibility

I am looking for a quicker way to toggle sticky keys than having to press the shift key 5 times each time.

Maybe some setting somewhere that allows defining a different activation hotkey?

Or perhaps some sort of command line option or registry key change would activate sticky keys? (then I could create a Windows shortcut with a suitable command and give it a hotkey.)

I have already considered using a utility like NirCMD to simulate the pressing of the shift key via a "sendkeypress shift" command repeated 5 times, but for some reason Windows 10 won't recognise this as a trigger for sticky keys.

Comment: For the most part the current method works well as a balance between when sticky keys are needed or (2) not needed.

Comment: Does pressing alternate left & right keys work? It does on my Mac for accessibility toggles, and is a bit faster than mashing a single key.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script uses <kbd>F9</kbd> turn on or off
sticky keys:

```
SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS:=0x003A
SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS:=0x003B
SKF_STICKYKEYSON:=0x1

VarSetCapacity(STICKYKEYS,8) ; DWORD cbSize;DWORD dwFlags;
NumPut(8,&STICKYKEYS,"UInt")
F9::
  DllCall("SystemParametersInfo","UInt",SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS,"UInt",8,"PTR",&STICKYKEYS,"UInt",0)
  dwFlags:=NumGet(&STICKYKEYS,4,"Uint")
  If (dwFlags & SKF_STICKYKEYSON)
    dwFlags-=SKF_STICKYKEYSON
  else dwFlags|=SKF_STICKYKEYSON
  ToolTip % "STICKYKEYS are " (dwFlags & SKF_STICKYKEYSON ? "ON" : "OFF")
  SetTimer,ToolTipOff,-1000
  NumPut(dwFlags,&STICKYKEYS,4,"UInt")
  DllCall("SystemParametersInfo","UInt",SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS,"UInt",8,"PTR",&STICKYKEYS,"UInt",0)
Return
ToolTipOff:
ToolTip 
Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Source : [Sticky key activation not work by hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/85662-solved-sticky-key-activation-not-work-by-hotkey/)

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)